# Update array element using JsonPath

Tags: arrays, replace, element, jsonpath

I am trying to replace a certain element in an a Json array using jayway's JsonPath in Java. Example:

```
{
"store": {
    "book": [
        {
            "category": "reference",
            "author": "Nigel Rees",
            "title": "Sayings of the Century",
            "price": 8.95
        },
        {
            "category": "fiction",
            "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
            "title": "Sword of Honour",
            "price": 12.99
        },
        {
            "category": "fiction",
            "author": "Herman Melville",
            "title": "Moby Dick",
            "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
            "price": 8.99
        },
        {
            "category": "fiction",
            "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
            "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
            "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
            "price": 22.99
        }
    ],
    "bicycle": {
        "color": "red",
        "price": 19.95
    }
},
"expensive": 10
```

}

Here I'd like to be able to replace the first book in the array. I can find the element by using this query `$.store.book.[?(@.author =='Nigel Rees')]`

I then use this code to replace the this node:

```
         Configuration configuration =  Configuration.builder()
           .jsonProvider(new JacksonJsonNodeJsonProvider())
           .mappingProvider(new JacksonMappingProvider())
           .build();
        DocumentContext pbContext = JsonPath.using(configuration).parse(theAboveJson);
        pbContext.set("$.store.book.[?(@.author =='Nigel Rees')]", someOtherJson);
```

But I noticed that instead of replacing, the new node is inserted at position 0 in the books array. Is there any way to actually replace the array element?